# Using NSTask in swift to execute a terminal command

Tags: swift, macos

Hi i'm trying to make a simple program with swift to execute this command that adds a white space in Dock:

`defaults write com.apple.dock persistent-apps -array-add '{"tile-type"="spacer-tile";}'; killall Dock`

this is the code i use:

```
    let task = NSTask()
    task.launchPath = "/usr/bin/defaults"
    task.arguments = ["write","com.apple.dock","persistent-apps","-array-add","'{\"tile-type\"=\"spacer-tile\";}';","killall Dock"]
    let pipe = NSPipe()
    task.standardOutput = pipe
    task.standardError = pipe
    task.launch()
    task.waitUntilExit()
    let data = pipe.fileHandleForReading.readDataToEndOfFile()
    let output: String = NSString(data: data, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding) as! String
    print(output)
```

I get no errors but nothing happens. Can someone help me please?

Comment: Please, do some research. On StackOverflow you can find posts dealing with `NSTask`, such as: [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35854503/swift-2-1-osx-shell-commands-using-nstask-work-when-run-from-xcode-but-not-when) or [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36779688/swift-nstask-function). Also, consult `NSTask` class reference pages.

Comment: who told you that i didn't ?, I came here because i didn't find any solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
  defaults write ... ; killall Dock
```

are *two* commands. When you type this line in the Terminal, it is passed
to your shell (usually "bash" on OS X), and the shell then executes
both commands sequentially.

On the other hand ,`NSTask` executes just a single command and does
nothing of the magic that a shell usually does. In your case
all the arguments, including the final "killall Dock", are passed as
arguments to `/usr/bin/defaults`.

A possible solution would be to execute *two* `NSTask`s sequentially,
one for the `defaults` command, and one for the `killall` command.

Comment: Okay i will try it and tell u the result, thanks mate.

Comment: Thanks mate it worked after some tweaking :D .. i will post the code as an answer.

Answer (score 4):

This is the code that worked for me:

```
    let task = NSTask()
    task.launchPath = "/usr/bin/defaults"
    task.arguments = ["write","com.apple.dock","persistent-apps","-array-add","{\"tile-type\"=\"spacer-tile\";}"]
    let pipe = NSPipe()
    task.standardOutput = pipe
    task.standardError = pipe
    task.launch()
    task.waitUntilExit()

    let task2 = NSTask()
    task2.launchPath = "/usr/bin/killall"
    task2.arguments = ["Dock"]
    let pipe2 = NSPipe()
    task2.standardOutput = pipe2
    task2.standardError = pipe2
    task2.launch()
    task2.waitUntilExit()


    let data = pipe.fileHandleForReading.readDataToEndOfFile()
    let output: String = NSString(data: data, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding) as! String
    print(output)
```